# Addressing input fields from form object via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms

This is either totally noob or I'm having a senior moment. I have an html form which I process with ajax on submit like so:

```
function submitSendSongForm() {
  var sendSongForm = jQuery(this);
  var formData = jQuery(this).serialize();  
  // Are all the fields filled in?

  if ( ! jQuery('#sendSongForm input#senderName').val() || ! jQuery('#sendSongForm #senderEmail').val() ) {
        // No; display a warning message and return to the form
        jQuery('#incompleteMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDelay).fadeOut();
        sendSongForm.slideUp().delay(messageDelay).slideDown();

        return false;

    }
            ....
```

OK, rather than the line `jQuery('#sendSongForm input#senderName')` how do I address that same input via the object `sendSongForm`?

I tried

```
sendSongForm.children('input#sendSongForm')
```

...but that does not work.

In Firebug I see that there is an array in sendSongForm which holds all the member fields. But shouldn't I be able to traverse `sendSongForm(the form object)` with jQuery as well?

If so how?

Answer (score 0):

The magic method you are looking for is `find`. Try this:

```
sendSongForm.find('input#sendSongForm');
```